# Missing scrolbar when viewing word docucment in QAxWidget

Tags: qt, ms-word, activex

I want to view a word document within a QT application. The QT version I have is 4.7.2, compiled with visual studio 2010 service pack 2. I have MS word 2003 installed. I have the following code:

```
QAxWidget* WordDocument=new QAxWidget ("Word.Document",this);
WordDocument-> setGeometry (QRect (10, 10, 621, 471));
WordDocument->setControl ("c:\\tset.doc");
WordDocument-> show ();
```

I can see the word document, however the scrollbars are missing. Any ideas what is wrong?